# angular1.5 component bind controller once

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make my first component in angular but i think i am doing it wrong.

In my controller, i call a resource to get data from a web service.

My component look like this :

```
.component('test', {
        templateUrl: '/layout/test.template.html',
        bindings: {
            data: '='
        },
        controller: myController
    })
```

i use my component like this in my template :

```
 <test data="row" ng-repeat="row in rowCollection"></test>
```

The problem is that i call the web service each time i use the component.

In fact, in rowCollection, i have all the data i need. Can i use my component without controller and just use the data passed.

Can you help me ?

thanks

Comment: If you have everything you need in rowCollection, then pass rowCollection to the component, just as you're passing data, and don't make the resource call.

Comment: Yes, you can use without controller.
Your component - is only one row, as i see. Why are you call a resource in this component?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Writing the problem makes me solve it.

myController was used by my page and my component.

I created a new controler for my component where i don't call the webservice and just use the data passed.

It works well.